# Dynamic actions on spark streaming context

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am running a standalone spark 2.0 cluster that will be running many small jobs. What I am trying to do is to run multiple actions on a DStream (as even assigning 1 core to each job is too high). I am also using pySpark, My code looks like something like this:

```
# Stream context reading data from Apache Kafka.
stream_context = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(.....    

# persisting the streaming context.
...

# Iterator to run different jobs.
iterator = {1: {'filter': ['metrics_of_kind_A', 'metrics_of_kind_AA'}, 2: {'filter': ['metrics_of_kind_B']}}

# Multiple actions on the same data set.
for _, value in iterator.iteritems():
    filtered_context = stream_context.filter(lambda x: x['metric_type'] in value['filter'])
    filtered_context.pprint()
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: **Try increasing window duration.** This might give a good amount of data to process in a go.

Comment: The problem is not the window size, I have lots of data, What seems to happen is the code above execute the filter for `metrics_of_kind_B` twice (instead of one `'metrics_of_kind_A' and 'metrics_of_kind_AA'`  and the other one `'metrics_of_kind_B'`

Comment: From what I understand it should be something with how the jobs are getting distributed between the workers. I also tried making the `iterator` a `Broadcast Variable` but still got the same result.